# Where can I modify the default ID/name used when dragging parts/tasks from the toolbar into the Visual Studio design surface?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Doing my best not to duplicate a question, but I'm coming up with nada on this one.  So in a nutshell, lets say we are in Visual Studio 2019 within an SSIS project, and I drag a SQL Task onto the design surface of my package.  There is a default name of "Execute SQL Task".  Is there a way to modify the default name applied during design time so I can prepopulate with best practice prefixes, i.e. from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SSIS-Component-Naming-44cd39bc

I have found no solutions at this point other than editing each task manually like we all typically do - looking to see if this is a shortcut to prefill best practices.

No applicable code to show on this.

Answer (score 1):

you have to manually edit each task. Microsoft doesn't handle this as each organisation has its own coding standard. So the best Microsoft can do to enter the task with default name which can be edited by developers to implement their organisation coding standard.

Thanks